# Le temps grammatical pour les extraits historiques d'une dissertation soutenue

Tags: temps-grammatical, registre-soutenu

Je suis entrain d’écrire une dissertation soutenue pour un cours en université (l'enseignement supérieur).  Quelques sections de la rédaction sont historiques, c'est-à-dire je raconte les récits pour montrer la valeur de mes arguments.

Je ne suis pas sûr quel temps verbal (passé) d'utiliser dans ces récits.

**Par exemple :**

> Stendhal **représentait** lui-même dans son oeuvre...

C'est une action répétée (dans plusieurs textes), alors j'utilise l'imparfait, cependant je ne sais pas si c'est correct car Stendhal est mort.

**Un autre exemple :**

> Aristote l'**a transformé** de l'individu à la communauté.

Une action singulière, mais le moment, où la transformation est passé, est imprécis.  C'est-à-dire qu'Aristote a causé cette transformation, mais sans en savoir.

**Un autre exemple :**

> Dans son *Politique*, Aristote **examinait** le lien entre la société
>   et la vertu personnelle.

Alors, le lien est (était?) examiné par Aristote dans son essai *Politique*.

---

**Sommaire :**

La rédaction est soutenue, alors je voudrais écrire avec un style qui correspond.  Devrait-je utiliser le passé composé ou le passé simple ?

Est-ce que j'utilise le temps correct dans mes exemples ?

Comment: Intuitivement, j'utiliserais le présent, pas le passé. Peut-être parce l'esprit de l'auteur reste présent dans son œuvre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C'est essentiellement une question de goût, aucun n'est réellement choquant. Mais je préfère dans ce cas utiliser le présent

> Stendhal représente lui-même dans son œuvre…
>
> Aristote la (le?) transforme de l'individu à la communauté.
>
> Dans son *Politique*, Aristote examine le lien entre la société et la vertu personnelle.

qui place le propos sur le plan de la vérité intemporelle. À mon avis ça donne plus de force à l'argumentation et ça fait plus épuré qu'un temps passé.